# DAX Summing Values in Another Table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new to DAX.

I have 2 tables. Let's call them `Table_1` and `Table_2`.

Let's say they look like this:

```
Table_1

ID     Table_2_ID     Person
1      1              Steve
2      1              Steve 
3      1              Steve
4      2              John
5      2              John
6      3              Sally


Table_2     Sales
1           100
2           50
3           5
```

I want to return results that look something like this:

```
ID     Table_2_ID     Person     Sales
1      1              Steve      100
2      1              Steve      100
3      1              Steve      100
4      2              John       50
5      2              John       50
6      3              Sally      5
```

How can I return this with a Dax function?

I know I need to use LOOKUPVALUE and/or the RELATED function, in combination with SUM, but I'm not sure how.

I'm not looking to produce a table, but a measure that when I use it in combination with other columns in Power BI, it applies the appropriate amount to each person in `Table_1`.

Comment: You dont need to use LOOKUPVALUE; Just create a relationship between this table based on ID <-> Table_2_ID  and create a measure to SUM sales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done either by a calculated column or by a measure.

CC in Table_1:

```
Sum_Tab2 = 
var t2_ID = [Table_2_ID]

return
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Tabel_2'[Sales]),
    'Tabel_2'[ID] = t2_ID
)
```

Measure:

```
SumTab2_measure = 

var currentT2ID = MAX('Tabel_1'[Table_2_ID])

return
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Tabel_2'[Sales]),
    'Tabel_2'[ID] = currentT2ID
)
```

No relationships needed. However, for the measure to work in a visual table the [Tabel_2_ID from Tabl_1 needs to be present with this solution.

These may have to be slightly altered depending on your other filter dependencies and such so that they behave as you want them to.

Comment: Hi , I tried replacing the `t2_ID` on the return statement directly, instead of creating a `var`, however it fails. can you please explain why adding the `var t2_ID` wont have the error?

Comment: You can, skip using the variable but then you have to put the filter argument within a FILTER()-function. 
I prefer using variables since I find the code more easy to read/understand, but that's just my pov.